Flutter: How to remove this from Bottom Navigator

I'm not sure what this shadow/highlight effect is called but how do I remove this?
@override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Scaffold(
      body: child,
      bottomNavigationBar: BottomNavigationBar(
        items: const <BottomNavigationBarItem>[
          BottomNavigationBarItem(
            icon: Icon(Icons.home),
            label: 'Feed',
          ),
          BottomNavigationBarItem(
            icon: Icon(Icons.groups),
            label: 'Groups',
          ),
          BottomNavigationBarItem(
            icon: Icon(Icons.person),
            label: 'Profile',
          ),
        ],
        currentIndex: _calculateSelectedIndex(context),
        onTap: (int idx) => _onItemTapped(idx, context),
        elevation: 0,
      ),
    );
  }

This is my code right now

Wrap your BottomNavigationBar() with Theme() and provide ThemeData.
bottomNavigationBar: Theme(
      data: ThemeData(
        splashColor: Colors.transparent,
        highlightColor: Colors.transparent,
      ),
      child: BottomNavigationBar(
        items: const <BottomNavigationBarItem>[
          BottomNavigationBarItem(
            icon: Icon(Icons.home),
            label: 'Feed',
          ),
          BottomNavigationBarItem(
            icon: Icon(Icons.groups),
            label: 'Groups',
          ),
          BottomNavigationBarItem(
            icon: Icon(Icons.person),
            label: 'Profile',
          ),
        ],
        currentIndex: index,
        onTap: (value) {
          setState(() {
            index = value;
          });
        },
        elevation: 0,
      ),
    ),


The BottomNavigationBarItem is not a widget but more of a container class which BottomNavigationBar needs for the items inside it.
So you will need to override BottomNavigationBar and you can create your own CustomBottomNavigationBar
